# Drawer navigiation load content with BLoC

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I'm trying to load content or page from my drawer with BLoC. I'm using `flutter_bloc: ^4.0.0`

MenuBloc

```
class MenuBloc extends Bloc<MenuEvent, MenuState> {
  @override
  MenuState get initialState => Dashboard();

  @override
  Stream<MenuState> mapEventToState(
    MenuEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is DashboardClicked) {
      yield Dashboard();
    }
    if (event is ProfileClicked) {
      yield Profile();
    }
  }
}
```

MenuEvent

```
abstract class MenuEvent{
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class LoadDefaultMenu extends MenuEvent {}

class DashboardClicked extends MenuEvent {}

class ProfileClicked extends MenuEvent {}
```

MenuState

```
abstract class MenuState extends Equatable {
  const MenuState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class Dashboard extends MenuState {}
class Profile extends MenuState {}
```

and i have this to `store` the event.

```
class NavModel {
  String title;
  IconData icon;
  MenuEvent menuEvent;

  NavModel({this.title, this.icon, this.menuEvent});
}

  List<NavModel> navigationItems = [
    NavModel(
      title: 'Dashboard',
      icon: Icons.insert_chart,
      menuEvent: BlocProvider.of<MenuBloc>(context).add(
        DashboardClicked(),
      ),
    ),
    NavModel(
      title: 'Profile',
      icon: Icons.person,
      menuEvent: BlocProvider.of<MenuBloc>(context).add(
        ProfileClicked(),
      ),
    ),
  ];
```

But the problem is on this part `List<NavModel> navigationItems`. I get this error

> Error: This expression has type 'void' and can't be used. menuEvent:
>   BlocProvider.of(context).add(
>           DashboardClicked(),
>         ),

when i change to this

```
menuEvent: MenuEvent.DashboardClicked
```

i get this error

> Error: Getter not found: 'DashboardClicked'.
>         menuEvent: MenuEvent.DashboardClicked

How can i fix it? did i miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the **DashboardClicked** is sub class,

change code from :

```
menuEvent: MenuEvent.DashboardClicked
```

to :

```
menuEvent: DashboardClicked()
```

in **NavModel** class

Comment: i get this error `The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MenuEvent'.`

Comment: try this :  menuEvent: DashboardClicked()